# Weird delay in UIPopoverController dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

Maybe this is purely simulator related.  I have not tried it on an actual device yet.

I'm on the latest greatest MacBook with a 1TB flash drive, and 95% free processor, and less than full memory consumption.

I have a UIPopoverController with 4 items in it, sized to those items.
There's nothing complicated or multi-threaded or long running in any way associated in the UIPopoverController in question.

I've set the appear and dismiss animation at 0, yet when I tap on an item in the list, there seems to be an random indeterminate delay between 0 and .4 seconds in the popover disappearing.  Of course the 0 is expected, but the times when it's nearly a half second is very noticeably longer and disconcerting.

Any idea what may be causing that?

Code that shows the popover...

```
-(IBAction)theLandImpsButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    iRpNameValuePopover *thePopoverContent = [[iRpNameValuePopover alloc] init];
    thePopoverContent.theTableValues = [self getLandImpsChoicesList];
    impsLandPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:thePopoverContent];
    thePopoverContent.thePopoverController = impsLandPopover;
    impsLandPopover.popoverContentSize = [iRpUIHelper sizeForPopoverThatHasTitle:NO andListContent:thePopoverContent.theTableValues];
    impsLandPopover.delegate = self;

    [impsLandPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.theLandImpsButton.bounds inView:self.theLandImpsButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
}
```

Code that dismisses the popover...
BTW, there is no evaluation time incurred here `[self userChoiceIsValid]` because it simply returns YES right now.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _theChosenNameValueItem = [self.theTableValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self acceptUserChoiceAndClose];
}


// This contentViewController is encapsulated INSIDE a UIPopoverViewController, and this class cannot itself
// close the popover which contains it, hence the need for the reference to the popover controller
// It is the popover's delegate... the one that created the popover, that is able to close it.
-(void)acceptUserChoiceAndClose
{
    _theUserChoseAValue = NO; // Start by assuming they didn't chose a valid value.

    if ([self userChoiceIsValid])
    {
        // Set variable that indicates the user chose a value which can be saved to core data, and/or presented on screen.
        _theUserChoseAValue = YES;

        // Close the popover.
        [_thePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];

        // Notify the class that presented the popover that the popover has been dismissed.
        // It will still be available to the dismissal method where code can retrieve the user's choice, and set the popover to nil.
        if (_thePopoverController.delegate && [_thePopoverController.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:)])
        {
            [_thePopoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:_thePopoverController];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self showValidationFailureMessageToUser];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can understand whats the issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Pavan  Hah... well, the code has changed so much over the past 18 months, I can't even find this code anymore.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex are you telling me you no longer display pop overs anywhere? ;) Perhaps how you do it now, etc. lol

Answer (score 2):

Dismissing the `viewController` in main thread will solve the issue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check it out in the profiler and see what the time is being spent on.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403).

Answer (score -1):

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverView;
//////
```

Dismiss it...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [popOverView.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            popOverView = nil;
        });
    });
```